# Remove actionbar item blue background

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am creating an actionbar with custom looking buttons that I put in the icon section of menu.xml.

The problem is that, when I press them, I see both the selected version of the image of the button and the blue background of the holo theme.

This is my menu.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/current_position"
        android:icon="@drawable/ab_location_layer"
        android:menuCategory="container"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="Current position">
    </item>

</menu>
```

The ab_location_layer is this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ab_location_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ab_location" android:state_pressed="false"/>

</selector>
```

The ab_location_layer contains an image that is smaller than the actionBar.
How is possible to remove the blue background on actionbar? I am also using actionbarsherlock.

Thanks

Comment: add your code please, and try to use selectors , you can fixe that

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the answer on ActionBarSherlock Mailing List:

you have to put this

```
  <item name="android:selectableItemBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@null</item>
```

to your theme and not in ActionBar theme